# Swift Changing Navigation Bar in a ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

So here's my problem.
I added a empty ViewController to a NavigationController.
The problem is that when I add a View to the empty ViewController the navigation bar becomes unclickable I can't add back buttons or change the title.

I'm using Xcode 6.1 6A1052d.

Answer (score 1):

You don't add buttons directly to navigation, but to the `navigationItem` of contained view controller. For example,

```
class ContainedViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: But when I add a ViewController which already has a view and link it to my navigationcontroller the navigation bar remains fully editable.